# Pandas Combining one DataFrame with Diff of another with a different shape

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine these two dataframes (DF1 and DF2) but only on the records that are not in the first dataframe (DF1). In the below example I want the result to only pickup the records 0,1,4,5 not merging 2,3 as they already have a complex and unit appearance in DF1. 
I tried merging with no luck and np.where

`np.where(df1[['complex','unit']] != df2[['complex','unit']])`
which resulted in `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`

**DF1**

```
company complex unit location   datetime            serial     seq  interval
3        6       10  UpMaster     2017-07-21 00:33:37  1505.0  3400.0      1554
4        6       11  UpMaster     2017-07-21 00:59:44  1505.0  3401.0      1567
5        6       10  UpMaster     2017-07-21 01:25:41  1505.0  3402.0      1557
6        6       A   UpMaster     2017-07-21 01:51:45  1505.0  3403.0      1564
7        6       13  UpMaster     2017-07-21 02:17:48  1505.0  3404.0      1563
```

**DF2**

```
index   complex   unit
0        7         1807
1        4         7
2        6         10
3        6         A
4       10         110A
5        6         12
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
company complex unit location   datetime            serial     seq    interval 
3        6       10  UpMaster     2017-07-21 00:33:37  1505.0  3400.0      1554
4        6       11  UpMaster     2017-07-21 00:59:44  1505.0  3401.0      1567
5        6       10  Down         2017-07-21 01:25:41  1505.0  3402.0      1557
6        6       A   UpMaster     2017-07-21 01:51:45  1505.0  3403.0      1564
7        6       13  UpMaster     2017-07-21 02:17:48  1505.0  3404.0      1563
8        7       1807  NaN       NaN                   NaN     NaN         Nan
9        4       7     NaN       NaN                   NaN     NaN         Nan
10       10      110A  NaN       NaN                   NaN     NaN         Nan
11       6       12    NaN       NaN                   NaN     NaN         Nan
```

**EDIT:: The Append method worked well thanks!**

`df1 = df1.append(df2[-df2['unit_id'].isin(df1['unit_id'].unique())], ignore_index=True)`

**Above is the final solution i went with after adding in unit_id unique identifier.  Without that a clever solution was suggested to make a key from the 2 semi unique fields.**

```
df1['key'] = df1['complex'].astype(str) + ' ' + df1['unit'].astype(str)
df2['key'] = df2['complex'].astype(str) + ' ' + df2['unit'].astype(str)
df1 = df1.append(df2[-df2['key'].isin(df1['key'].unique())],ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.drop('key',axis=1)
```

Comment: `pd.concat`, `drop_duplicated` by `complex`and `unit`,

Comment: Also In DF2 index 5 , should it include in new DF ?

Comment: Good catch Wen I updated the Desired Results to fit that. Im not sure how the `pd.concat, drop_duplicated by complexand unit` would work as there may be multiple records for a unit/complex pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can still use the append with a conditional, but just need to create an extra `key` column:

```
df1['key'] = df1['complex'].astype(str) + ' ' + df1['unit'].astype(str)
df2['key'] = df2['complex'].astype(str) + ' ' + df2['unit'].astype(str)
df1 = df1.append(df2[-df2['key'].isin(df1['key'].unique())],ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.drop('key',axis=1)
```

**Previous Answer**

I think you can use `append` with a conditional to do what you want:

```
df1 = df1.append(df2[-df2['complex'].isin(df1['complex'].unique())],ignore_index=True)
```

This will leave the extra columns `company, location, datetime` etc. with np.NaN values. You can later populate the `company` column with your desired results

Comment: Close but i need to check on two columns **'complex'** and **'unit'** and there may be a complex appearing in both but say 1 missing unit in DF1 that is included in DF2.  I updated the data example to show this.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this requirement

Comment: Something odd is going on.  I took the key idea and brought in a unique Unit_ID from the Database to simplify things.
`df1 = df1.append(df2[-df2['unit_id'].isin(df1['unit_id'].unique())], ignore_index=True)`  GAH ill update original question this is too limiting

Comment: Updated my original question to show the data return problem clearly.